# Horror story about boy being turned into a mannequin

Tags: identification-request

I vaguely remember a story that I read in english class during middle school (ca 2008-2010 in Sweden) about a boy being turned into mannequin. From what I remember the boy was dipped in waxed by evil villain and then while still alive placed in the shop windows. The shop might have been Harrods, though I very unsure about this detail. I tried searching on the internet but unfortunately I didn't find anything. The story was quite short and also think it might have appeared in the textbook we using though it might been adapted from elsewhere. The level of english should also been quite easy. One thing that reminded me of the story is the following lines from this QI clip: https://youtu.be/Fki5pi_Y5IY?t=274 (starting at ca 4:30) though it might just be me remebering things incorrectly.

Thank you very much in advanced for any help.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you remember any other details - like was it a novel or just a short story, was it originally in English, where was it set? Since you mention Harrods as an unsure detail, are you at least sure that the book was set in Britain? There's a checklist in the [tag info](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) which might help to jog your memory for details.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor Thank you very much for your comment. I have now tried to add some more detail to the question.